# Visibility Converters in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am creating a android application using MvvmCross, in which I have to show and hide some controls in listview depending upon the value. For that I have created a visibility converter in PCL like this

```
public class VisibilityValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, MvxVisibility>
    {
        protected override MvxVisibility Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            return (value == true) ? MvxVisibility.Visible : MvxVisibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }
```

and I am using this value converter in my layout page like this

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text QuestionText"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            local:MvxBind="Text OptionA" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxBind="Text OptionB"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxBind="Text OptionC"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            local:MvxBind="Text OptionD"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4" />
    </RadioGroup>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="159.0dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"       
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"       
        local:MvxBind="Visibility TexboxVisible,Converter=Visibility" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But it's not working. It's not hitting the breakpoints in PCL value converter.

I have also tried to use MvxVisibility plugin but it's also not working.
I think I am doing something wrong. Can someone help and let me know how to use visibilty converters inside listview in android.

ViewModel

```
   public class Question
    {  
        public string Type { get; set; }        
        public bool RadioVisible { get; set; }
        public bool TexboxVisible { get; set; }  

    }

private List<Question> _questionList;
        public List<Question> QuestionList
        {
            get { return _questionList; }
            set
            {
                _questionList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => QuestionList);


            }
        }
 private async void ShowQuestionsList(int assignmentId)
        {
QuestionList = await _service.GetQuestionListByAssignmentAsync(assignmentId);
if (QuestionList != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Question q in QuestionList)
                        {


 if (q.Type != null)
                            {
                                if (q.Type == "S")
                                {
                                    q.RadioVisible = false;
                                    q.TexboxVisible = true;
                                }

                                else if (q.Type == "O")
                                {
                                    q.RadioVisible = true;
                                    q.TexboxVisible = false;
                                }
                            }
}
}
}
```

Comment: We use the MvxVisibility plugin just like in your Xaml. You dont need to define a ValueConverter when you use the Visibility Plugin. And: you need to add the plugin both in the PCL project and in your Android project.

Comment: I have added that plugin in android project and PCL but its not working. can you please give me the syntax for binding visibility with controls?

Answer (score 4):

My breakpoint in my Testconverter is fired as it should. My code:

```
public class TestMethodValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, MvxVisibility>
{
    protected override MvxVisibility Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value ? MvxVisibility.Visible : MvxVisibility.Collapsed;
    }

}
```

And the View-Xaml:

```
local:MvxBind="Visibility MyBoolProperty, Converter=TestMethod"
```

But there is another problem. The android view elements can't change the visibility with the MvxVisibility enum. They need a `Android.Vioews.ViewStates` value.

So you need to add the converter in the Android project. Thats why we use the MvxVisibility-Plugin.

**Edit**

Your viewmodels should all inherit from `MvxViewModel` and the properties, which are used for binding need to implement the property-changed call `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Property);`. Otherwise nobody knows about changes. Thats the first point.

But the Converter should work at the first time without that (as far as I know). So I don't see anything other which can go wrong.. so try to create a simple clean project only with that problem and one single View-Element to reproduce what can go wrong..

Comment: Yes I agree, that the android view elements can't change the visibility with the MvxVisibility enum. That's why I tried using MvxVisibility-Plugin, but its not working. Is there any compatibity issue with android version ?

Comment: I don't know any issues. I had the same problem once because I forgot the VisibilityPluginBootstrap in my Android project. Have you added that class?

Comment: Yes I have added that class.I also checked the stack trace and plugin is loaded. I am not getting any errors but the visibility binding is not working,

Comment: Hmm.. Ok. So the binding itself can be a problem. Please post your ViewModel or the implementation of your Property 'TexboxVisible'

Comment: I have edited the code of layout page, please check. TextboxVisible is a boolean property.Actuly I am using Mvxlistview and the posted layout is the itemtemplate for that. So the TextboxVisible is propery in the listview which I am passing as the Itemsource to the Mvxlistview. I have to do the same with radiobutton group.

Comment: Have you seen that in your layout you named the property 'TexboxVisible' and in your comment you said 'TextboxVisible' (missing t char).

Comment: TexboxVisible is the property name. I am binding the same.

Comment: Ok. Can you post the implementation of your property in your viewmodel?

Comment: Edited my answer. The clean-project-hint worked for me multiple times in the past

Comment: Visibility plugin works for me,I have removed all other visibility converter code and now its working. Thanks alot for your help.